How to fix the following clappr player error in next js
Browser errorImplementationConsole error
Bug is occured when player component is unmounted. This is implemented on media web-site for streaming format media source. There is no any bug when the player is rendered initially. But If you switch into other movie from another, the above error is occured. I didn't find proper solution to fix this error.
